# Narrowing type based on another field in same instance

Tags: typescript

I have the following class and an array with instances of that class:

```
class Org<Name extends string = string> {
    id: keyof typeof orgs; // 'tk' | 'ig'
    name: Name;
    
    constructor({id, name}) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const orgs = {
    tk: new Org({ id: 'tk', name: 'Tiktok' }),
    ig: new Org({ id: 'ig', name: 'Instagram' })
};
```

Elsewhere I have the following interface:

```
interface Data<
  A extends Org['id'] = Org['id']
> {
    orgId: A
    orgName: typeof orgs[A]['name'] 
}
```

What I would like: if `orgId` is `ig`, `orgName` can only be `Instagram`. But it should fail if `orgId` is `ig` AND `orgName` is `Tiktok`. How do I do this?

```
const test1: Data = {
    orgId: 'ig',
    orgName: 'Instagram' // correct
}

const test2: Data = {
    orgId: 'ig',
    orgName: 'Tiktok' // should throw error but doesn't
}
```

Comment: You need `Org` to have more information (or at least `typeof orgs` needs to have more information) and then `Data` should be a discriminated union type, as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NB8PdW). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Quick and helpful as always! This could work, but I want to make sure that the key of `orgs` always matches what's passed as `id` to the `new Org`. So if `const orgs = { abc: new Org({id: 'def' })}` should fail while `const orgs = { abc: new Org({id: 'abc' })}` shouldn't.

Comment: @jcalz that could work but `const test2: Data = { orgId: 'ig', orgName: 'Tiktok' }` no longer seems to error

Comment: Yeah okay forget that; instead I'd just generate `orgs` like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXvk8m) so that it can't be the wrong type.  Does that work now?

Comment: @jcalz So I simplified my code in my question. But in actual code `orgs` is a separate file with named exports. Meaning: `export const ig = new Org(); export const tk = new Org();` etc. And I'd import them as `* as orgs`, so `typeof keyof orgs` would have made sense. I need them to be named exports for tree-shaking so `makeOrgs` might not work for this use case.

Comment: This is starting to feel like scope creep; I’m not sure how to enforce a constraint on code I can’t access.  I’ll try another approach when I get a chance (generic helper function to check `orgs`) but right now it’s my bedtime so it probably won’t be for 8 or 9 hours.

Comment: Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WG8kMw) meet your needs now?  Let me know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work you need the compiler to know the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `id` properties of the values in `orgs`.  And therefore you probably want `Org` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of `id` also:

```
class Org<K extends string, N extends string> {
    id: K
    name: N;

    constructor({ id, name }: { id: K, name: N }) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const orgs = {
    tk: new Org({ id: 'tk', name: 'Tiktok' }),
    ig: new Org({ id: 'ig', name: 'Instagram' })
};
/* const orgs: {
    tk: Org<"tk", "Tiktok">;
    ig: Org<"ig", "Instagram">;
} */
```

Since you care about verifying that each key of `orgs` holds an `Org` with the same `id`, we can write a generic helper function to check that:

```
function checkOrgs<T extends { [K in keyof T]:
    Org<Extract<K, string>, any>
}>(orgs: T) { }

checkOrgs(orgs); // okay
```

If `orgs` were misconfigured, you'd get an error there.  (It would have been nicer to use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) instead of calling a no-op function, but that operator affects inference in a way that doesn't work for this use case. )

---

And now we can use `orgs` to defined `Data`:

```
type Orgs = typeof orgs;
type Data = { [K in keyof Orgs]:
    { orgId: Orgs[K]['id'], orgName: Orgs[K]['name'] }
}[keyof Orgs];

/* type Data = {
    orgId: "tk";
    orgName: "Tiktok";
} | {
    orgId: "ig";
    orgName: "Instagram";
} */
```

First we define `Orgs` to be the type of the `orgs` variable, i.e., [`typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) `orgs`, just to make it easier to refer to the type.

Then `Data` is a so-called *distributive object type* (as coined in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) where we make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and calculate for each property in `Orgs` a corresponding `orgId`/`orgName` pair, and then [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that mapped type to get a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) or possible valid `Data` object types, as desired:

```
const test1: Data = {
    orgId: 'ig',
    orgName: 'Instagram' 
}; // okay

const test2: Data = { // error!
    orgId: 'ig',
    orgName: 'Tiktok' 
}
// Type '{ orgId: "ig"; orgName: "Tiktok"; }' 
// is not assignable to type 'Data'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyBOBzAPAaWgUwB4BcMDsATGCHeAS30QBpoA5TXA46UiqgPmgG8BYAKGhDo5QgC5oqAcOj4wAWwwS6AbgHThwAPb42AV2A4t8ABTcRhWnMXQAvhPOiJqKwqX07ASh4aZQnAAW5BAAdKLQALwWaoJ+-kGh1hiRsm4xMrYCmfwC2ro40MaIMFF8sf4A1hL4GADucEhmFhIA5DgVLa6KrQAq5BVGHV7UviKI1XUNiE1O0C3kiJ2p3XMAkvlgiPAKLV5ZMQD0AFTQeaSFSBAOo+0SCCgARO0PtA99A1oVDxzpwgt3SGQDwWL2gD3WpE223k3xitmgRwO6n4ADM9PhDOQdKcAhhgBV7hBkD1GHgiDBzABtdCUaAVDAATy0KOgPQAumJRvdkABRXDbQxoWhsSiIDi0MD4BkcLIcExFK6s7zmbLAXH4wnyy6eFTQA4HQoVMAM5E4BkAB2ShJSZstzIuxRituSABEwDgwCkqTT8HTGfbCRzRuYiqtxFMINS2ZT5oQWmzaEU6G4AcUozGkvG7FlKfSmSzAzEBMdoM7oG6PV7RqHw08vr8hEmU2D3oMHnDoAAfHzlB1hiTAxDt6tIZMrcEbLYKYf8eGI5FnAp4UgARgkFc9pRHiH7cwWnW3Y-cLQhHqn8l2+tOxngeJwWQXOnOy5wACZ1+7Nzw9QaMPB4MYACE267vMiwjL2TYrC0rafLsD78FePQWskLQhkgu6Du2DpHgOsH1nYuzBLIWgFJAEALHIABGIDJEYpYoXMG4tCEyJAA)